# PHP form completely blank when trying to populate using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database that holds customer orders. I am trying to create a form that a user would enter after selecting the ID of a row they would like to modify.

What the code below is suppose to do is auto-populate a html form with all of the data from the MySQL row. It would take the ID given to it by a previous php file and then use that to grab the row it needs from the database. Unfortunately, no matter what I change or do, the webpage only produces blank boxes where the data is suppose to be.

Here's the code for edit.php (the form that is suppose to auto-populate.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <form action="update_submit.php" method="post">

<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$servername = "server";
$username = "book";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "book";

$db_selected = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if  ($db_selected->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $dbc->connect_error);
}

if(!empty($_GET['ID'])){
   $id = intval($_GET['ID']);
}

try {
    $results = $db_selected -> prepare("SELECT * FROM customerorders WHERE ID = ?");
    $results -> bind_param("i", $id);
    $results -> execute();

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e -> getMessage();
        die();
    }

$row = $results->get_result()->fetch_assoc();

?>

    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="lastName" value="<?php echo $row['lastName']; ?>" required><br />
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $row['firstName']; ?>" required><br /> 
    <input type="text" name="email"  value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>" required><br />
    <input type="text" name="phoneNumber"  value="<?php echo $row['phoneNumber']; ?>" required><br />  
    <input type="text" name="department" value="<?php echo $row['department']; ?>"  ><br />
    <input type="text" name="typeOfOrder" value="<?php echo $row['typeOfOrder']; ?>" required><br />
    <input type="text" name="vendor" value="<?php echo $row['vendor']; ?>" required><br /> 
    <input type="text" name="product"  value="<?php echo $row['product']; ?>" required><br />
    <input type="text" name="PONumber"  value="<?php echo $row['PONumber']; ?>" required><br />
    <input type="text" name="accountNumber"  value="<?php echo $row['accountNumber']; ?>" required><br />
    <input type="text" name="dateOrdered"  value="<?php echo $row['dateOrdered']; ?>" required><br />
    <input type="text" name="dateExpected"  value="<?php echo $row['dateExpected']; ?>" required><br />
    <input type="text" name="comments"  value="<?php echo $row['comments']; ?>" required><br />
    <input type="submit" name="sumbit">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have error reporting on and nothing ever comes up when I try to find problems. I've also switched around my ' and " multiple times just to see if it ever makes a difference. Nothing I have tried seems to work. I've also looked through every stack overflow question I could possibly find relating to my issue and I still can't find anything that would fix my problem.

Any help is appreciated. I am a novice to php and MySQL so I apologize in advance if the code seems nonsensical or if there is an already obvious solution.

Comment: Try adding `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to your error display set of commands

Comment: Can you do a print_r($row) and see what is produces.

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica I am manually adding the connection to just this page. I have a connection.php, I just wasn't sure whether or not it was the problem, so I opted to having all of the connection information on the edit.php file.

Comment: @RiggsFolly It still does not give me an error when I include that.

Comment: @AbsoluteBean I gotcha, I understand.

Comment: @SidHussain When I put in the print_r($row) it prints out nothing.

Comment: Installing XDebug would be helpful and then do step by step and see where it crashes.

Comment: by the looks of things, this will crash if $_GET['ID'] isn't set. I would error handle that first